# How to use an ASP variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

As the title says, I'm just trying to use an ASP variable in Javascript, but the code that I have is not able to do so. How do I achieve this?

```
<%
    dim strMyString
    strMyString = "hello there"
%>

<HTML>
<body>

    <%=strMyString%>
    <p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = <%=strMyString%>;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The only output I am getting is "hello there". Expected output is "hello there" twice.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"The **only** output I am getting..."_ - There's not just one. You just need to look at the correct location which would be the console of your browser.

Comment: don't you have to quote the string?

Comment: @Andreas I see it as "hello there" in the console with an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. It should be displayed on the page when it's working properly.

Comment: @dandavis I do have quotes around the string though

Comment: _"I do have quotes around the string"_ - Only on the server (ASP), but not on the client (JavaScript).

Comment: @Andreas O wow... can't believe I missed that. It works. Still getting used to ASP. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example generates the following on the client:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hello world;
```

This is obviously invalid JavaScript and will therefor throw a syntax error (check the console).

You have to wrap the string in quotes:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<%= strMyString %>";
```